# Why I put the DELETE router after GET, the DELETE endpoint did not get triggered

Tags: go, gorilla

I was creating restful API with Golang and I put the delete router after the getOne router by index, and the delete router never got triggered? I don't know why? When I reverse them, it works!
Can someone know the reason??

This is for Building Restful API with Golang.

Not works:

```
myRouter.HandleFunc("/article", createNewArticle).Methods("POST")

myRouter.HandleFunc("/article/{id}", getOneArticle)

myRouter.HandleFunc("/article/{id}", deleteArticle).Methods("DELETE")
```

Works!

```
myRouter.HandleFunc("/article", createNewArticle).Methods("POST")
myRouter.HandleFunc("/article/{id}", deleteArticle).Methods("DELETE")
myRouter.HandleFunc("/article/{id}", getOneArticle)
```

When I test the api using postman with DELETE methods, it always trigger the getOneArticle and respond with the delete item, but did not actually delete in the database!

Comment: think of the way this is executed.... `DELETE /article/{id}` matches `myRouter.HandleFunc("/article/{id}", getOneArticle)` so the program doesn't continue to the next route

Comment: but what is I put DELETE first, the following getOneArticle still works,

Comment: So DELETE request matching GET operation???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using gorilla/mux. When an HTTP request comes in, this router tries to match routes in the order in which you add them.

When you add the route without specifying an HTTP method, it applies to all HTTP methods.

So, if your more specific route matching the DELETE method comes first, then it will match DELETE method calls, and the next route will match all methods. While it would match DELETE also, an actual DELETE call would never reach it because of the route preceding it.

But if you reverse them, the route which doesn't specify an HTTP method will match all methods, including DELETE.

Answer (score 0):

Gorilla/mux matches the routes in an order in which you have defined them. Without specifying the Http Method it will match it no matter what you have selected from the postman i.e. GET, DELETE

for instance, you have a route /todo/1 and the method is not specified, It will run in case of GET, DELETE, POST and PUT.

**Note**
Same route with method DELETE defined under the first one will never get triggered.